# What is the difference of resource and dependencies in KieRepository's addKieModule method?

Tags: java, drools

The drools API documentation and example shows that it let user load jars to produce a `KieModule`. But I was confused with the resource and dependencies in KieRepository's `addKieModule` method(it is `addKieModule(Resource resource,Resource... dependencies)`). The documentation doesn't have explanation about this.